# Call to a member function query() on a non-object in profile.php on line 82

Tags: php, pdo, authentication, forms

Working on echoing the users questions out so far I can insert the values and   this is working thru the php admin but its not working thru , the form on    the users profile page?

The error says ,**"Call to a member function query() on a non-object in profile.php on line 82"** The php code on this line is as follows

```
   $query1=$db->query("SELECT id,title,question,username FROM  QnA WHERE username='$dbusername'");
```

**The rest of profile.php is below**

```
   <?php 
     session_start();
     $dusername=$_GET['username'];
    if (isset($dusername)){
        require('connect.php');

        $userquery =$db->query("SELECT id,firstname,username,lastname,email FROM users WHERE username = '".$dusername."'");
                while ($row =$userquery->fetch()){
                        $id=$row["id"];
                        $dbusername =$row["username"];
                        $dfirstname = $row["firstname"];
                        $demail =$row["email"];
                        $dlastname =$row["lastname"];

                        }

    }

 ?>
  <html>
   <head><title><?php  echo $dfirstname;?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/profile.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="container">

<?php
echo'
 <div id="qform"><center>
  <form action="ask.php" method="post">
   <b>Title</b>
   <br/>
   <input type ="text" name="title"/>
   <br/>
   <b>Question</b>
   <br/>
   <textarea name="question"></textarea>
   <br/>
   <b>This is to make sure your not a robot  2+2=</b>
   <input type="text" name="plus"/>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"name="submit"/> 
   </form></center>
   </div>
    ';
?>  
<div id="questions">
 <?php 

   $query1=$db->query("SELECT id,title,question,username FROM  QnA WHERE username='$dbusername'");
  //$query2=$db->query("SELECT * FROM answers");

   while($asked=$query1->fetch()){
    if($asked['username']==$dbusername){
     echo '<div class="asked"><b>Title</b><br/><b> ',$asked['title'],'</b>   <hr/><br/><b>Question</b><br/><b>',$asked['question'],'</b></div><br/><br/>';

   }
     else if(!$asked['username']==$dbusername){
          error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo 'No questions have been asked';
        }

 }
     ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

**The form is in the profile.php the action for the form is in a separate file named ask.php which is below.**

```
   <?php

   //form action below
   require('profile.php');
   session_start();
   require('connect.php');
   $plus=$_POST['plus'];
   $title=$_POST['title'];
   $question=$_POST['question'];
   $dusername=$_SESSION['username'];
         if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          if(!empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['question'])&& $plus==4){
              $query="INSERT INTO `QnA` (id,title,question,username) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
              $query=$db->prepare($query);
              $query->execute(array(' ',$title,$question,$dusername));
                echo'succes';
                header("Location: profile.php");
            }
         else{
             error_reporting(E_ALL);
             echo " Fill in all Slots or you gave the wrong answer to the security question";
            }
         }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is not returning True at all :

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
```

that's why it is going in else statement.

You are using isset function for username field, but you should check for Submit button. Try replacing following lines :

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submitbtn" />
```

AND

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
```

It should work then :)

Comment: Thank you so much it was what was wrong with it .. God bless

Answer (score 0):

You have error in you query add space between `ANDpassword='`, maybe this should work

```
$query="SELECT  * FROM  users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1" ;
```

to debug you error try

```
$res =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Take note this query is vulnerable in SQL Injection, maybe you should try using mysqli or PDO for security purposes.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on SQL injection protection , I tryed what you said with the space but the output is still that Else statement .    @RxV

Comment: did you try using `$res =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` to debug your error

Comment: i think you query didnt return any return you have many spaces in your query. try given query above.

Comment: try to echo the `mysql_num_rows($res)` how many it will return?

Comment: Its is echoing 0 ? @RxV

Comment: well it not getting any results from your query

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password" id ="password"/></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Log In" /> &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <input type="button" value="Register" onClick="location.href='register.php'" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php


require('connect.php');
session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['username'])
{
header("Location: home.php");
 }
else{
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
 require('connect.php');


 //According to user's input

  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $query="SELECT  * FROM  users WHERE username='".$username."'AND password='".$password."'";

 $res =  mysql_query($query);

 //check username and password for match
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){

 //Sets username to the comment session so no username has to be input


$_SESSION['username']=$username;

// jumps to secure page 

 header ("Location: home.php");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As above mentioned you are getting `0` rows values, there may be space or some thing else in you query so do below.

echo this query

```
SELECT  * FROM  users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'
```

and execute this query manually in database and see what is happening with this query. And correct your query accordingly.